# How To Call Method of another package from string method name in Go

Tags: go

Suppose I have two package like

> -a
>
> -b

**a** have some methods like this

```
 func TestOne() { //something }
 func TestTwo() { //something }
```

I need to call package **a**'s methods from package **b** but by only string method name. Like i get the string "TestOne" and calls for the method TestOne(). How can i get that done.

**Edit :**
I have Read about `reflect`. but `reflect` needs an **struct and functions be a member of that struct.** What if My functions are not member of a struct? just plain methods in a package. and the calling methods and called methods are in different package. Then?

NB. There could be some methods that have parameters as well.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Golang: pointer to function from string (function's name)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017979/golang-pointer-to-function-from-string-functions-name)

Comment: @icza I read that qustion and answer. But their solution which they said to use reflect. And reflect needs an struct and functions be a member of that struct. What if My functions are not member of a struct? just plain methods in a package. and the calling methods and called methods are in different package. Then?

Comment: Then the answer is no, you can't do that without something like a pre-populated name-function map as seen in @LightWeight's answer.

Comment: @eror Read `mnagel`'s answer to the linked question. It should be the second answer from the top at this time. 

You **can** use reflect to call functions as long as you have the function's handle, which you can get via a map. You're misinterpreting the fact that you **cannot** get a free function's handle **solely** via reflection. As long as you build a `map[string]interface{}` that returns the functions by name yourself, you can call the function via `reflect.ValueOf` followed by `Value.Call` or `Value.CallSlice`

Comment: @Jsor Thanx, brother. I resolved it with a map you specified. :) But still in my idiot mind one question is Present - if i dont have a map how can i do it.

Comment: @eror You cannot get types at the package level without constructing it yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Like LightWeight said in his answer, you can use reflection.

You use the reflect.ValueOf method to get the value of the type. Then you can use the MethodByName method to get the function value. Once you have the function value you can call the Call method to execute it.

Code Sample

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type TypeOne struct {
}

func (t *TypeOne) FuncOne() {
    fmt.Println("FuncOne")
}

func (t *TypeOne) FuncTwo(name string) {
    fmt.Println("Hello", name)
}

func CallFuncByName(myClass interface{}, funcName string, params ...interface{}) (out []reflect.Value, err error) {
    myClassValue := reflect.ValueOf(myClass)
    m := myClassValue.MethodByName(funcName)
    if !m.IsValid() {
        return make([]reflect.Value, 0), fmt.Errorf("Method not found \"%s\"", funcName)
    }
    in := make([]reflect.Value, len(params))
    for i, param := range params {
        in[i] = reflect.ValueOf(param)
    }
    out = m.Call(in)
    return
}

func main() {
    t1 := &TypeOne{}
    out, err := CallFuncByName(t1, "FuncOne")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //Return value
    _ = out
    out, err = CallFuncByName(t1, "FuncTwo", "monkey")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    //Return value
    _ = out
}
```

Comment: reflect needs an struct and functions be a member of that struct. What if My functions are not member of a struct? just plain methods in a package. and the calling methods and called methods are in different package. Then?

Comment: Yeah, I'm an idiot :) I knew that when I was looking at it. There is no way to directly get the package functions. You can create a map of all the functions you would want to call. `funcMap := map[string]interface{}{"TestOne":TestOne,"TestTwo":TestTwo}` and then use `reflect.ValueOf(funcMap["TestOne"]).Call()` to execute it as in the Sample Code above.

Comment: why will u be an idiot, brother. I am the one here who asks stupid questions. :P :P thank though. Trying what you just described.

Comment: @monkey_p Finally a solution which does what was asked. `funcMap := map[string]interface{}` way described in the comment is the right way to call methods not part of a struct IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use reflect in go. This link may be help you
https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/
and http://mikespook.com/2012/07/function-call-by-name-in-golang/

```
func foo() {
    // bla...bla...bla...
}
func bar(a, b, c int) {
    // bla...bla...bla...
}
funcs := map[string]interface{}{"foo":foo, "bar":bar}
```

Comment: reflect needs an struct and functions be a member of that struct. What if My functions are not member of a struct? just plain methods in a package. and the calling methods and called methods are in different package. Then?