# Iterate over imported package functions

Tags: go

I have a package with many functions. I want to test all those functions simultaneously for error handling, because the error handling is common to those functions.

Is there a way to iterate over the imported functions within my test file?

Comment: Do you mean "test functions by reflection" as I did 3 years ago? (http://stackoverflow.com/q/20823836/6309)

Comment: Related / possible duplicates: 1. [Call all functions with special prefix or suffix in Golang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384473/call-all-functions-with-special-prefix-or-suffix-in-golang); 2. [Golang: pointer to function from string (function's name)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017979/golang-pointer-to-function-from-string-functions-name)

Comment: @VonC: I want to avoid manually listing the functions `var funcNames = []string{"Func1", "Func2", "Func3"}`

Comment: This says "no": https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/9Di5eHK2eQ0